# Several tables vs one table with many columnfamilies

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable

I am in the process of designing a Bigtable database.
I have two structures to persist:

1. "Data" (in SQL database I would put it in one table): type, reprocessed data, timestamp.
2. Payload: raw, non-processed Data information, timestamp.

Question: should I make two separate tables for Data and Payload? Or maybe it is better to make one table (for example, Data). In this table, two columnfamilies (processed and unprocessed) with corresponding columns.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using one table with two columnfamilies versus two tables?

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to have fewer tables as much as possible. Sending requests to many different tables can increase back-end connection overhead, resulting in increased tail latency. Having multiple tables of different sizes can disrupt the behind-the-scenes load balancing that makes Bigtable function well.

Refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#tables) for more guidance on designing your schema.

Comment: Do I understand well that it is better to create a few different columnfamilies instead of a few tables?

Comment: Yes michf, it is better to create few different column families instead of more tables. However, some points to consider is both data and payload should have some relations so that they can be referenced by same set of keys. Otherwise merging them only increase rows of the table which again can cause performance issue.